# Force Stop Python Script in Task Manager Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a script that parses log files running in task manager on Windows Server 2012. I made some updates to the script so while it was running, I ended the task, then disbaled it. However the status of the task still showed as "running". I thought this was just a bug so I started the task again when I had pushed the changes. This however caused the script to attempt to double queue the log files creating duplicate attempts in the server table that the script updates. How do I make a script halt whatever it's in the middle of in task manager?
Settings below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you reply if this answers your question, or mark the answer as answer?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly : You want to stop the running script through for example task manager.

Could you show the 'Action' tab? Usually the task scheduler starts a process, for example, python which is visible in the task manager, which you can close forcefully.